# bidirectional (biphasic) RMS value

Tags: rms

I have searched online and can find RMS calculations for many waveform shapes. What I cannot find however, is a calculation for a typical neuro stimulation wave as shown in the attached image.

What I don't see is how to factor in the pulse duration, deadtime (time at 0V), repetition frequency, and amplitude to determine the RMS value. Also, does the negative going pulse affect the RMS value, since the waveform is discontinous due to the deadtime?

Any help or thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: waveform image]

Comment: RMS is the square root of the integral of the square of the waveform. Does this help already?

Comment: I mean, Janka is right: the actual definition of how you calculate it is in the name: Root mean square value. You square your signal, then you calculate the mean (integrate and divide by integration length), then you take the root. done.

Comment: Thanks for the response and comments. Doesn't this get us to the same place based on feedback:
Vrms^2= Vp^2/T*t1 
where Vp = peak negative or positive voltage
T= pulse duration
t1= one time interval of T
Therefore Vrms= Sqrt(Vp^2/T*t1)
Does this look right or am I missing something?

Comment: I think this would also get to the same answer:  Vrms= Sqrt(Vp^2*t1/T) Yes?

Answer (score 1):

> Any help or thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

The RMS value of a negative voltage is exactly the same as a positive voltage hence, the waveform can be redrawn to make the thought process a little easier: -

[image]

This boils down to 16 time slots where 1 in 16 has a zero value hence the power into a 1 ohm resistor (for instance) is \$\frac{15}{16}\cdot 10^2\$ = 93.75 watts and, converting back to RMS voltage it is 9.682 volts.

Comment: Aha a downvote - can anyone explain why?